# добавление в синтезатор речи свою модель голоса python

Tags: python, синтезатор-речи

с помощью RVC я сделал голосовую модель, теперь думаю, как реализовать, чтобы, допустим, pttsx3 вместо предустановленных на виндовс синтезаторов использовал эту модель. чего только я уже не пробовал и с помощью transformers и с помощью tensorflow, но всë безуспешно. может кто-то знает как это решить?

Comment: этот ваш вопрос чем-нибудь принципиально отличается от предыдущего?

Comment: принципиально нет, просто ищу способы для реализации, т.к прошлые показали неудачные результаты